# Define an array with prefixes using the range operator

Tags: arrays, powershell

From [this](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html) I can see I can do this with range operator:

```psh
$myArray = @(4..9)
```

But how can I do something like this:

```psh
$myArray = @(usr4..9)
```

I have tried various deviations of this with nonsense errors:

```psh
$myArray = 4..9 |
%\{ "usr$_"\}
```

Comment: What, exactly, would you have as an output? And what's the deal with lorem ipsum anyway?

Comment: I just want to add usr4, usr5, usr6 to the array. I had to write half an assay to post. no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would that do?

```
@(4..9) | % {"usr" + $_}
```

Comment: Precisely. But it seems this prints the users. How do i avoid this?

Comment: @user3019059 Simply assign the result to a variable or send it down the pipeline to do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Side note: `@()` is not required. `4..9 | % { "usr$_" }` will suffice.